# Running WordPress with wp-env prompts for FTP credentials

Tags: wordpress, docker, ftp

When using wp-env for a local WordPress development environment, I am unable to install or update plugins and themes. It prompts for FTP credentials, which of course don't apply to the local Docker environment.

This occurs on Windows 10 with Node.js 14.15, although there may be other variables at play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to resolve this issue in a typical local environment is to add the following to the **wp-config.php** file:

```php
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

However, the **wp-config.php** file is not available to edit when using wp-env. Fortunately, you can still add config values by creating a file called **.wp-env.override.json** in the root directory. Create the file, and add the following:

```json
{
    "config": {
        "FS_METHOD": "direct"
    }
}
```

Restart wp-env, and it should no longer prompt for FTP credentials.